# Nested loops wuth mult table

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Ok I am stuck on a program. I need to create a multiplication table that multiplies a value only 3 times as 3 is given as a stop value. 1 needs to be multiplied like such (1*1,1*2,1*3). And the next set needs to be multiplied with its value being first multiple (2*2,2*3,2*4) and so on. I get nested for loops are being used but just need a nice starter to get me going

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j < i+3; j++) {
       // multiply i and j here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a square matrix (if you wanted to go higher than 3)

```
for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    //multiply here
    }
}
```